# getaddrinfo addrinfo result in stack or heap

Tags: c, networking, struct, heap-memory, stack-memory

I am a bit confused at least.
getaddrinfo() call 'updates' a pointer to a addrinfo struct, all is well when I am going to use the addrinfo in the same scope (that function) but what happens if I copy the struct to another one (by assigning it).

Please help me understand the undergoing basics (not seeking advice for alternative approaches).

Correct me if I am wrong:
a) getaddrinfo() requires a pointer to struct-pointer to addrinfo.
b) getaddrinfo creates a addrinfo struct in the current function scope and updates the pointer required in a)

Now my real question: i would like to store that addrinfo somewhere else. Using an assigning to an other pointer does not do a deep copy, and after the function all the pointers become invalid?

Better give an extremely simplified example:

```
void GetAddrInfo(struct addrinfo *update)
{
    struct addrinfo *res;
    getaddrinfo(xx,xx,xx,&res);

    //is this save? After this 'scope' ends all pointed fields are invalid?
    //this doesn't copy the linked list ai_next.
    *update=*res; 
}
```

Directly using &update on getaddrinfo seems to not work because the problem remains: the original struct get destroyed after the function scope ends.

Anyone able to give me more insight here (please explain what gets created where and destroyed where, stack, heap all info is welcome)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

> the original struct get destroyed after the function scope ends

No, the struct's **pointer** is destroyed. The rest of the data is still in the heap. This would be a memory leak if you don't call `freeaddrinfo()` when you're finished with the result.

> i would like to store that addrinfo somewhere else

Since the data still exists, feel free to copy the pointer; no need for a deep copy. From your example:

```
void GetAddrInfo(struct addrinfo **update)  /* pointer to pointer */
{
    struct addrinfo *res;
    getaddrinfo(xx,xx,xx,&res);
    *update=res;  /* save the pointer to the struct */
}
```

You would simply call this function with:

```
struct addrinfo *mycopy;
GetAddrInfo(&mycopy);
```

Comment: Thanks for your feedback. Correct me if I am wrong: normally when I create a struct instance it will be created on the stack right and 'cleared' after the current scope is finished? So getaddrinfo is a special case here? Is there a way I am able to find what functions are keeping the data?

Comment: @Ger All local variables are on the stack, correct. But you aren't creating the `addrinfo` struct; `getaddrinfo()` is creating the struct for you with `malloc()`, which is why it's in the heap. All you're creating is the **pointer** to the struct. Your **pointer** goes away when the function ends, but the struct itself is still in the heap.

Comment: These are basic questions perhaps; but are all other c functions which update a struct pointer working in the same way?

Comment: @Ger `getaddrinfo()` is kind of unique in that it takes a pointer to a pointer and generates a linked list for the user. Off the top of my head, I can't think of any other function that does that. Most C functions take a simple struct pointer (not a pointer to a pointer); those functions generally expect the user to pre-allocate the struct, which the user often does simply on the stack. When in doubt, look-up an example on the interwebs.

Comment: @Ger: No, you'll need to check documentation for each function

Comment: Thanks guys; was not able to find it in my documentation, perhaps I was not looking at the correct ones though, the freeaddrinfo() should have woke me up on it.

Answer (score 1):

`getaddrinfo` allocates a list of `addrinfo` structures, and gives you the pointer to the head of the list. You release all allocated memory by passing this pointer to `freeaddrinfo` when you're done with it.

What you're doing is safe enough, but leaks memory.

```
void GetAddrInfo(struct addrinfo **update)
{
    getaddrinfo(xx,xx,xx,update);
}


addrinfo * myai;
GetAddrInfo(&myai);
freeaddrinfo(myai)
```

This approach will not leak memory - you're simply retrieving a pointer to the addrinfo list head.

Comment: I know about freeaddrinfo(), wanted to keep the discussion clear. So you say the struct will not be 'invalidated' after the function scope ends? So in effect it's not removed until I call freeaddrinfo on the head?

Comment: @Ger Teunis: Exactly. It's allocated from some private allocation mechanism and completely safe until you call freeaddrinfo

Comment: @Ger Teunis: Although, you cannot pass `update` to freeaddrinfo - it's a copy of the fields of `res` it doesn't point to the original head of list. I'll update the answer.

Comment: Thanks, so getaddrinfo is a special case in that it doesn't clear the addrinfo struct on scope exit?